# Am I missing something in my JavaScript code that I may be overlooking?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple app that when you click on a blurred image, the un-blurred image will appear, but it does not seem to be working for some reason. I used Bootstrap in this app to allow it to be mobile friendly, although I do not believe that it is causing my JS code to break.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row row-padding center-block">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="zero" src="zeroblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="one" src="oneblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="two" src="twoblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="three" src="threeblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="four" src="fourblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <img id="five" src="fiveblur.jpg">
        </div><!-- end col-lg-4 col-sm-6 -->
      </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container-fluid -->
```

(I only included the markup pertaining to my JS code)

and here is my JS code:

```
function init() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++);
        images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
};

function showAnswer(eventObj) {
    var image = eventObj.target;

    var name = image.id;
    name = name + ".jpg";
    image.src = name;
}
```

window.onload = init;

Comment: You can use `onload="init()"` in body tag also.

Comment: @whd But you shouldn't. You should really never use inline HTML event handlers because they create spaghetti code, don't follow the DOM Event Model standard and create global function wrappers for the specified value of the property to execute in, which changes the biding to `this` in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++);
    images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
```

Should be this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
}
```

Comment: @Chaaaley Don't forget to mark as answer!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that your loop is doing exactly nothing but changing the value of i.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < images.length; i += 1) ; // semicolon means end-of-statement (ie: do nothing)
```

So technically your last image should be clickable (because `i` has been changed to the last number before the length of the array).

If you remove the semicolon, the statement should just work.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < images.length; i += 1)
  images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
```

However, this is why I tell the people on my teams that they should always use braces around `if`, `while`, `for`, etc...

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < images.length; i += 1) {
  images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
}
```

We're now dealing with a much more explicit set of behaviours.
That's not to say that languages with significant whitespace are bad, but to say that it gets confusing when you start mixing and matching when whitespace matters and when it doesn't, within the same function, let alone the same file.

Additionally, I have them use more functional techniques.

```
images.forEach( img => img.onclick = showAnswer );
```

forEach isn't hugely functional, but it's better than worrying about funny loop behaviour, at least.

Of course, if `images` is a NodeList of some kind (eg: comes from `document.get____( );` or `document.querySelectorAll( )`, then you have to take it one step further:

```
[].slice.call(images).forEach( img => img.onclick = showAnswer );
```

Which is better broken into two steps:

```
function toArray (arrLike, start, end) {
  return [].slice.call(arrLike, start, end);
}

toArray(images).forEach( img => img.onclick = showAnswer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `init` function has an extra semicolon at the end of the `for` line.

Best practice is to always use brackets, so you avoid this kind of problems.

So replace your `init` function with this and it should work just fine:

```
function init() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
    }
};
```

Comment: Gee. Sounds like my answer from 5 minutes ago.

Comment: StackOverflow was slow with the updates, did not see that there before refreshed the page :S

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -2):

You cannot add an event listener to the images like this:

```
images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
```

Use:

```
images[i].addEventListener('click', showAnswer);
```

Comment: You can add an event listener that way. It's not good, but you can and it will work (with some funky behaviors that wouldn't otherwise happen).

Comment: To add it that way, as far as I know, you'd need to add parentheses as well, because the field otherwise looks like this `onclick="showAnswer" `and as far as I know, that will not fire. However you cannot add a parentheses in the code, because obvious reasons, thus, you can either but it all as a string literal or wrap it in an anonymous function, but plainly like this, it should not work, as far as I know.

Comment: @Dellirium That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Dellirium When you wire up an event handler inline in the HTML, you must use parenthesis because you are writing code that should be executed by another function when the event occurs. When you wire up in JavaScript to an event handling property, you don't use parenthesis because that would invoke the function right then and there and all you want to do is reference the function. Either way is not recommended. Use the DOM standard of `addEventListener()`. With this method, you also don't use parenthesis because you just want to refer to the function.

Comment: @Juhana of course it does, writting `showAnswer` and `showAnswer()` are two completely different things, or at least should be, I am not certain if in this particular situation they are, but they should be

Comment: The fact remains that there's nothing technically wrong about `images[i].onclick = showAnswer;`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for clarifying why it is different in javascript and html. I am aware that if I was to write it in javascript with parentheses it would fire immediately which is precisely why I said to avoid it. Was not aware that if you write it without them, html document would understand that it should run it, because setting the value of the "onclick" attribute in HTML this way is not really telling it to run it. Unless HTML will swallow the non-parentheses call

Comment: @Juhana Yes, there is.  Explain how you would wire up two functions to be called when the click event occurs please.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's why I said "technically" wrong. The OP isn't wiring up two functions.

Comment: @Juhana It is technically and functionally wrong. It does not follow the W3C standard for DOM Event Handling and it fails to offer robust options.  Event handling properties and inline HTML event handlers should ALWAYS be avoided. There is no reason to use them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's no reason to use them, yes, but they work in this case (you said it yourself in the first comment). What I'm saying is that Dellirium's answer doesn't solve the OP's problem. I'm sure we can agree to that.

Comment: I agree on that, and as I noted in my comment to Scott, as he clarified it, I thought that HTML will not fire an event that was added to it's field. It does not solve the problem that the question asked about, however I am not wrong in anything that I did to correct his mistake up there. What he wrote there is bad code and should be fixed like I proposed.